# discord.py get user answer out of dm

Tags: python, discord.py

I am new to python and I want to make an bot that asks some Questions and then the user can answer and the bot saves the answer in a varible that I can send to me at the end.

I get this Error:

**discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'messaage'**

Im new to stackoverflow so im sorry for mistaking something.

```
async def bewerbung(ctx):
  Answer = ""
  await ctx.message.delete()
  em=discord.Embed(Title="Test", description="Test")
  em2=discord.Embed(Title="Hello", description="Test")
  channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
  await ctx.author.send(embed=em)
  def check(m):
          return m.content is not None and m.channel == channel
  await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
  Answer= "" + ctx.message
  await ctx.author.send(embed=em2)
  print(Answer)
```

Comment: Context has no attribute `messaage`, unless your error message is a typo, you used `messaage` instead of `message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Ask A question to the user then wait for the user using following code

```py
msg = await client.wait_for("message")
```

Then you can use `msg` for checking the content user sent.

like this

```py
        if msg.content == "Hi":
            await member.send(
                "Hi , How Are Ya"
            )
        else:
            await member.send("Bye")
```

Some Thing Like This , Talkn about users msgs being stored in var , it will be stored in `msg`

Hope It Helps , More Here [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for)